# unable to upload file on onedrive using OneDrive APIs

Tags: onedrive

Can any one help me.
I'm using OneDrive API's for upload files to OneDrive. But problem is that I have full path of file. How can I upload this file using OneDrive API's.

Basically, I have A link and full path of file which I need to upload file to OneDrive. How is this possible to upload file on click the link.

Comment: What language are you using, and what platform are you targeting?

Also, have you checked the OneDrive APIs or samples?

Comment: you question is too vague